# How to calculate day of the week from timestamp? (DST)

Tags: math, language-agnostic, timestamp

I am developing code for device where datetime library is not available (note: floats also unavailable), so I have to do math myslef.

My timestamp is seconds from 1 Jan 2000 (in UTC).
In configuration of device I have:

- current timezone as number of hours +/- from UTC
- dst as number of hours to add

I need to know:

- current day of week
- current hour

Calculating current hour is pretty easy:

```
timestamp % 86400 # seconds from midnight
```

Calculating day of the week (1-monday,7-sunday):

```
dayofweek = (timestamp - 86400) % (86400*7) / 86400
if dayofweek = 0:
    dayofweek = 7
```

notes:

- 86400 = seconds in one day

But before calculations I should:
1. add timezone hours
2. add DST hours

The problem is how to calculate if DST hours (for European Summer Time only) should be added or not? I need to do this efficiently beacuse I have very limited computing power and I need to do this as fast as possible :-)

Comment: @selbie what does leap years have to do with day of the week? In leap year we add 1 day to month, not one day to the week. I don't divide by years, I divide by days/weeks.

Comment: my bad.  Leap year does matter for computing year/month/day.  But you are correct for day of week, it is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

To determine if DST is applied, you need to know day and month as well. In Europe, the change is on last weekend in March/last weekend in October. Would suggest you apply timezone offset without DST, do your calculations to get hour, day of week, day and month, and then if you are in DST, you may need to adjust any or all of these values (depending on the original value of hour, it may just be hour that needs adjusting).

By doing the timezone offset first, you are getting the local hour/day of week/day values correct without DST, then the DST adjustment is trivial.